# Custom progressDialog xml

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to know where I can find the original XML used for the progressDialog because I want exactly the same design except change color of the background, border,text color and center also the rotating image.

I tried to use my own XML layout, but I didn't succeed in reproducing the same design as the original one (the small arrow, the line between the title etc....)

http://thedevelopersinfo.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/with_title2.jpg

Big thanks !

Comment: It's work....but maybe not in your country ! it's just the default progressDialog

Comment: On my browser if i remove ?type=w3 the image is very small. Here is the same one : http://thedevelopersinfo.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/with_title2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in your android sdk directory.

\android-sdk\platforms\android-XX\data\res\layout\progress_dialog.xml

Comment: Thanks. I try to use it directly by   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
where R.layout.custom_progress_dialog is the exact content of the progress_dialog.xml. But an error appear and i have a force close.... I try to use with "Dialog" and not ProgressDialog, but with that i don't have the small arrow and the separator. How to do it ?

Comment: `06-28 08:19:15.165: E/AndroidRuntime(820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 08:19:15.165: E/AndroidRuntime(820):     android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be     called before adding content`

Comment: `ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);` (the xml is the same as \android-sdk\platforms\android-XX\data\res\layout\progress_dialog.xml)

Comment: Don't use ProgressDialog. Use [AlertDialog and AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) instead and inflate the layout you're using.

Comment: Thanks, but finally i used a Dialog, with a design which looks like alertDialog (even not the same).